# Copy constractor with memory allocation and deallocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, copy-constructor, allocation

I have written following piece of code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

///Driver class
class driver
{
    char *name;
    int age;
public:
    //Default contructor
    driver(){}

    //Constructor for initialize
    driver(int a, char* n)
    {
        age = a;
        int len = strlen(n);
        //Allocate memory for name
        name = new char[len];
        strcpy(name, n);
    }

    //Copy constructor
    driver(const driver &d)
    {
        name = new char[strlen(d.name)];
        strcpy(name, d.name);
        age = d.age;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout<<"Name: "<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"Age: "<<age<<endl;
    }

    ~driver()
    {
        if(name != NULL)
        {
            delete name;
        }
    }
};

class automobile
{
    driver drv;
    char* make;
    int year;

public:
    automobile(driver d, char* m, int y)
    {
        drv = d;
        int len = strlen(m);
        make = new char[len];
        strcpy(make, m);
        year = y;
    }

    void print()
    {
        drv.print();
        cout<<"Make: "<<make<<endl;
        cout<<"Year: "<<year<<endl;
    }
    ~automobile()
    {
        if(make!=NULL)
        {
            delete[] make;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    driver d(15, "Jakir");
    automobile a(d, "Toyta", 1980);
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I have to use char* not string and allocate memory dynamically. But when I run the code, there occurs an error of memory leaks. I think it's due to the copy constructor and de-allocation memory of driver class. How to fix the error? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not following the Rule of Three, and fyi, `delete nullptr;` is a no-op.

Comment: `delete [] name;`, not `delete name;`

Comment: You're consistently allocating one `char` too few; remember that C-style strings have a terminating `0`.

Comment: delete [] name; and delete name; cause the same result, crush :(

Comment: initialize name to NULL in the default constructor

Comment: @JakirHossain So this code crashes? That's not a memory leak. Most likely reason for a crash is that you don't do `+1` when youallcoate strings. And also what stefaanv says.

Comment: check my answer. He need to +1 strlen, for space for the '\0'. He needs the name=0 in ctr, since he might delete it, and he needs to follow rule of three, and he does use the operator=, and is getting the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of stuff wrong with this code, but I will list a few of the big ones.

1. As smentioned by others, you `new char`'s need to be one bigger than they are.
2. You default constructor should set name to nullptr.
3. you have a memory handling error whenever you do an assignment, eg on this line:    `drv = d;` because it calls the default operator=, which is incorrect in your case. Ther eis the Law of the Big Three which loosely states that whenever you need either a (non-trivial) copy constructor, copy assignment operator, or destructor, you'll most likely need to implement the others, too. You need to write an operator=!

Based on existing code, I would expect your operator= to look vaguely like this:

```
//assignment operator
const driver&operator=(const driver &rhs)
{
    if (this==&rhs) return *this;
    delete[] this->name;
    this->name = new char[strlen(rhs.name)+1];
    strcpy(this->name, rhs.name);
    this->age = rhs.age;
    return *this;
}
```

Do all that, and your core dump goes away.

PS  Please, please just learn to use std::strings, new-ing char arrays and managing the memory yourself is a bad bad move.

Comment: Can you please modify the code for me? I tried last two days. but in vein. I have to use char* because it's an assignment. thanks in advance.

Comment: I wrote an operator= for you, I am sure you can add a +1 to your char array lengths, as per john's answer,and I am sure you can set name=0 in the constructors by yourself too.

Answer (score 0):

`name = new char[len+1];` not `name = new char[len];`

`name = new char[strlen(d.name) + 1];` not `name = new char[strlen(d.name)];`

`delete[]` not `delete`

Need to define an assignment operator `driver& operator=(const driver &d)` in order to follow the rule of three.

Similar changes need to `automobile`.

However I don't see a memory leak, what makes you think you have one?

Comment: The third point is undefined behaviour, so it could lead to a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

In main method you need to do like this,

```
driver* d = new driver(15, "Jakir");
automobile* a = new automobile (d, "Toyta", 1980);
a->print();
if ( a ) delete a ;
if ( d ) delete d ;
return 0 ;
```

Comment: I think that stack memory couldn't clean properly, So you can delete those memory by yourself.

Comment: Adding those new's here does noting beyond making it look more like Java.